# Decryption not able to get all the value and key

Tags: java, json, spring, encryption

Implemeting decrypt all everything and output will same as payload.

But i only manage to get the path of `teacher` key. and also the teacher key is missing.
is there is also way to get the student and teacher at desame time?

```
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class TestClass{
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    String secret = "secret";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/test.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;

    JSONObject teacher = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("teacher");
    String encrypt= (String) teacher.get("profile");

    String iv = (String) teacher.get("iv");

    byte[] newKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
    byte[] IVTest = Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv);

    String Decrypt = decryption(encrypt,newKey, IVTest);
    System.out.println("Decrypt output : "+ Decrypt);
}

public static String decryption (String cipherText, byte[] myKey,byte[] IV) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(myKey, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
    return new String(decryptedText);
}
}
```

Json payload

```
{
  "student": {
    "firstname": "Joan",
    "lastname": "lastname"
  },
  "teacher": {
    "profile": {
      "firstname": "Mary",
      "lastname": "lastname"
    },
    "iv": "ivvvv"

  }
}
```

Output of decryption

```
 +\r+pvb);{
    "profile": {
      "firstname": "Mary",
      "lastname": "lastname"
    },
    "iv": "ivvvv"

  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that IV is not correct or not base 64 encoded. What you get is about what you get if the IV is incorrect. As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#/media/File:CBC_decryption.svg) it is XOR'ed with the result of block cipher decryption. As you only get about 9 bad bytes you can tell that the IV decoding is not correct, as the last bytes are probably zero'ed out and thus OK. I'd try `iv.toBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` instead of base 64 decoding first.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes i think your correct i made it like this `iv.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`  and the `+\r+pvb);` in output is changing to like a wildcard or something `���z�j��k���` like this. what to do next?

Comment: What happens if you use the empty string? There is two things you can do: 1) keep guessing how the IV is encoded or 2) take the output **bytes** after decryption and XOR those with the ASCII of `"teacher": ` as that will give you the IV... XOR works both ways :) Of course, without doing this myself, I cannot tell what kind of IV is used. Furthermore, I don't know if the bad decryption displayed contains any non-printable characters and such, so I might be missing bytes.

Comment: Top. I don't think the question / answer will directly benefit anybody else and the iv handling has duplicates. So you can remove the question or self- answer it (so it doesn't stay open) :)